# Timebase error when encoding mp4 file

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video, encoding

[image: Here]
[image: Here]

I am using Blenders Video Sequence Editor and it won't let me render it. The message:

> Timebase 20999/500000 not supported by MPEG 4 standard, the maximum admitted value for the Timebase denominator is 65535

keeps popping up. I don't know what to do. It also won't let me save it either.

Comment: Could you add screenshot of Rendering options inluding Dimensions and output. Can you try changing frame rate from there to see if it works?

Comment: Answer to your most recent post, that's the same question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/56894/26541

Comment: @Jina please don't post the same question twice. Edit the original question.