# Timebase error when encoding

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video, encoding

I am using Blender's *Video Sequence Editor* and it won't let me render it. The error message...

> Timebase 20999/500000 not supported by MPEG 4 standard, the maximum admitted value for the Timebase denominator is 65535

...keeps popping up. I don't know what to do. It also won't let me save it either. Here are some screenshots.

[image: here]

[image: here]

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Frames Per Second

The output file format you've chosen, Xvid, does not support the frame rate you've chosen. Your error,

> Timebase 20999/500000 not supported by MPEG 4 standard, the maximum admitted value for the Timebase denominator is 65535

basically says: your frame rate (5 frames per second with a framerate base of 0.210, totaling 23.81 fps) isn't compatible with your output file format.

## How to fix

As far as I'm aware you can't fix it, you have to either change the fps or the output file format.

Happy Blendering!

Answer (score 0):

Just curious: why do you need a video with exactly 23.81 fps?

You might need to export your animation as an image sequence, and later use some external video encoding software to create a video with that special frame rate.

I tried using a Quicktime with MPEG-4 codec and it worked.